# No se puede acceder al usuario root usando con contraseña a través de ssh

Tags: login, ssh

Trato de realizar una conexión entre 2 Maquinas virtuales parrot linux. Cambié la configuración en `sshd_config` para tener acceso mediante root y aun así no acepta la clave.

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

También he cambiado la clave de root y sigo con el mismo problema.

Comment: Muchas veces, si intentas acceder mediante windows usando putty u otro gestor, te limita mucho el firewall, intenta desactivarlo e intentar de nuevo  la conexion.

Comment: Está usando el id root o un usario que puede actuar como root?  Es muy común para prohibir login usando "root" per se.  Puede loguear como otro usario y sudo.

Comment: Lo he intentado desde root y con una cuenta con Los privilegios de root  e verificado la contraseña   y es corrects y aun asi me sale  Permission denied please try again. Como si la contraseña estubiera mal pero la contraseña es la misma en ambas maquinas y ambas cuentas root y adicional pues solo era para testear asi que no entiendo el error cabe mensionar que para hacer sudo la contraseña si funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los parámetros que necesitas cambiar para poder conectarte a través del usuario root utilizando una autenticación por contraseña, son:

- PasswordAuthentication
- PermitRootLogin

Ambos valores los deberás poner con el valor `yes`.

Puedes editar el archivo `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, en esos campos, con algún editor de texto, o bien puedes correr los siguientes comandos (si es que aplican para tu caso).

```
sudo sed -ri.bak 's/^(PermitRootLogin )(.*)/\1yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed -ri.bak 's/^(PasswordAuthentication )(.*)/\1yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Después de editar ese archivo, reinicia el servidor ssh con `sudo service ssh restart`

Cabe destacar que esto en general es riesgoso porque la seguridad únicamente depende del tamaño y calidad de la contraseña root y ya no habría por qué escalar en los niveles de acceso ya que `root` posee todos.